# How to make window form application run in background?

Tags: c#, system-monitoring

I want to create GUI Application that run when window start like windows service. But windows service have no GUI. When window start my winForm is Hide and when user press some specific key then winForm show. I know for this i required keyboard hook. I also create winForm Application which work accurately but i want that it work in background and after window start when user press specific key the winForm will show.This winForm is only used to show data. Simply i want to create application like [Auto Capture PC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-U3MmX88J0) .

Any One have any idea please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your program into two parts.

First, you need to create a Windows service that provides the data collection/monitoring.

Second, create a WinForm application and implement your keyboard hook there. Have this program run when the user logs in. It will need to communicate with the service to get the data to display to the user.

Comment: Any helpful link to communicate between windows service and winForm?

Comment: I already created these two parts.